# Как сделать раскрывающийся блок в ReactNative?

Tags: react-native

Есть список пользователей. Нужно при нажатии на блок контакта, развернуть его на высоту содержимого. Пока не представляю как это сделать.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSelected: false,
      users: [
        {
          "name": "Isabel Dorsey",
          "email": "isabeldorsey@eschoir.com",
          "about": "Laborum nostrud occaecat quis non id pariatur amet. Proident ad exercitation incididunt consectetur velit dolore laborum consectetur deserunt labore. Reprehenderit sit nostrud ad nostrud magna nisi et mollit. Cupidatat tempor nisi amet do ullamco qui Lorem sit enim. Ut reprehenderit occaecat id dolore sint ipsum consectetur qui commodo ut magna Lorem. Dolor laborum ex aliqua sint exercitation nulla dolor voluptate sint occaecat reprehenderit aute nostrud.\r\n"
        },
        ...
      ],
    };

    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
  }

  changeState(isSelected){
    this.setState({ isSelected: !this.state.isSelected });
  }

  render() {
    let { isSelected } = this.state
    const { users } = this.state
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <Text style={styles.h2}>Список контактов</Text>

        <FlatList
          data={users}
          renderItem={({item}) =>
            <View style={styles.flatItem}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style = {[
                    styles.itemField,
                    isSelected ?
                      styles.resizeFieldPress :
                      styles.resizeField
                ]}
                onPress = { this.changeState }
              >
                <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.email}>{item.email}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.about}>{item.about}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          }
          keyExtractor={item => item.email}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlatList – добавить в него свойство extraData `extraData={this.state.selected}`, для перерисовки нужной ячейки, которая должна открываться. В renderItem сделай условный рендеринг ячейки для развернутого и свернутого состояния ;)

```
changeState = (index) => this.state({ selected: index });

<FlatList
      data={users}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <View style={styles.flatItem}>
          {index === this.state.selected ? (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[styles.itemField, styles.resizeFieldPress]}
              onPress={() => this.changeState(index)}
            />
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[styles.itemField, styles.resizeField]}
              onPress={() => this.changeState(-1)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.email}>{item.email}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.about}>{item.about}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.email}
    />
```

Comment: это примерный код, идеальный конечно должен быть другой. Контакт вынести в компонент и избавится от стрелочных функций в свойствах компонентов